# How can I disable login screen music?

Tags: league-of-legends

Now that Riot has implemented a queue system at login, I spend even 30 minutes in the intro screen. I would like to mute the music there, so that I can play other games, see videos, etc. while waiting. Is it possible in some way?

[image]

Comment: what system are you running? There are a few different answers but it depends on what OS your running.

Comment: @Ben I am running Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: In Win 7 you can selectively turn off sound per application, right?

Comment: @Yi Yeah right, now I kown it. Still too much Windows XP oriented :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tray open the volume mixer by clicking on the volume icon and selecting "mixer". Using this you can mute specific programs/games.

Comment: If you want to update the answer, in patch 1.0.0.112 Riot has implemented: 'You can now disable the Music at the main login page.'

Answer (score 6):

As of the latest patch, .12, there is an option on the log-in menu to disable the sound.

> The Login Queue will now update your
>   position more regularly The Login
>   Queue will no longer lock the focus of
>   the application You can now disable
>   the Music at the main login page

Answer (score 0):

I've never played the game but can't you delete/replace the music that is played in the files to stop it from having anything to play or plays a silent track?